# How to set the userinfo endpoint manually in OpenID-Connect-PHP?

Tags: php, openid-connect

We haven an external identity provider that provides us with an endpoint to do the user authentication (OpenID-Connect). However, the URL to fetch the userinfo after the authentication is not set (which is usually in the returned link).

The identity provider sent us the URL to get the userinfo from, but now we need to set the URL manually in the [OpenID-Connect-PHP script](https://github.com/jumbojett/OpenID-Connect-PHP).

With `function requestUserInfo()` there is:

```
 $user_info_endpoint = $this->getProviderConfigValue('userinfo_endpoint');
```

And this [function](https://github.com/jumbojett/OpenID-Connect-PHP/blob/05c3036964db76c9780fe3110c97fd17fd98191f/src/OpenIDConnectClient.php#L499):

```
function getProviderConfigValue($param, $default = null) {

        // If the configuration value is not available, attempt to fetch it from a well known config endpoint
        // This is also known as auto "discovery"
        if (!isset($this->providerConfig[$param])) {
            $this->providerConfig[$param] = $this->getWellKnownConfigValue($param, $default);
        }
        // ...
```

With `json_decode($this->fetchURL($well_known_config_url));`

I do not see where to set the "userinfo URL" manually in the code.

Setting `$client->setProviderURL($userinfo_url);` before calling `$client->requestUserInfo('role');` did not work.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there is no option to do it in the code of the library. Thus, you have these options:

- you can ask the identity provider to expose an OIDC metadata endpoint. Then, the library will be able to read the userinfo endpoint dynamically.
- you can modify the library so that it's possible to provide a configuration option for the userinfo endpoint. The library seems to be actively supported, so you could even open a Pull Request so that the change is incorporated into the official codebase.
- you can open an issue on the library's Github asking for that feature.

To edit the library I would probably go with something like the following. In the `src/OpenIDConnectClient.php` I would add this to the `OpenIDConnectClient` class:

```php
class OpenIDConnectClient
{
...

private $userinfoEndpointUrl;

public function setUserinfoEndpointUrl($url) {
   $this->userinfoEndpointUrl = $url;
}

...

public function requestUserInfo($attribute = null) {

$user_info_endpoint = $this->userinfoEndpointUrl;

if (!$user_info_endpoint) {
        $user_info_endpoint = $this->getProviderConfigValue('userinfo_endpoint');
}

...
```

In your project, you will find the library in `vendor/jumbojett/openid-connect-php`. Note that running `composer update` will overwrite any changes you make to the library. You may want to just copy that code to your project and modify it there (it's one file anyway).

Then in your code, where you create the client, you need to call `$client->setUserinfoEndpointUrl("...");` to set the configuration option.

Comment: 1. "you can ask the identity provider to expose an OIDC metadata endpoint." - They don't do it because of "privacy" concerns. Don't ask me...
        
2. "open an issue on the library's Github asking for that feature" ... I did 7 days ago, no reply: https://github.com/jumbojett/OpenID-Connect-PHP/issues/289
        
3. "modify the library so that it's possible to provide a configuration" → That's exactly what I hoped to get when asking here on SO. --- I need to know where to **change the library code** to set up the endpoint.

Comment: `They don't do it because of "privacy" concerns` - doh... I edited the answer with some guidance on how I would update the library. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I found out that it should be also possible by using function `providerConfigParam()` with `$client->providerConfigParam(array('userinfo_endpoint' => 'https://www.sso-website.org/userinfo')); `

Comment: True, then no changes are needed in the library code after all :)

Comment: Your help was leading to the solution. Thanks.